# How to 'enter' every n number in a nested for loop using python

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to write a python function with two for loops(one nested) and accept n number and form a grid. So far, I have this code and just need to be able to essentially 'enter' after the loop has ran through to n number.

```
def draw_grid(n):
for i in range(1,n+1,+1):
    for j in range(1,n+1,+1):#(1,n+1,+1) starts at 1, ends at n + 1, adds in increments of 1  
        print(j, end=' ')

draw_grid(3)
```

prints:

```
1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

goal:

```
1 2 3

1 2 3

1 2 3
```

so if I changed `n to equal 5` it would then 'enter' every 5th number. I have tried playing around with using `end=' '` in different positions to get that to work but it just changes the way individual numbers are spaced, not every `n` number.

Comment: just add an empty `print()` outside the inner loop

Comment: or just do `print('\n'.join(' '.join([str(i+1) for i in range(3)]) for _ in range(3)))` without any (explicit) fors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `print()` statement after the nested for loop.

```
def draw_grid(n):
for i in range(1,n+1,+1):
    for j in range(1,n+1,+1):#(1,n+1,+1) starts at 1, ends at n + 1, adds in increments of 1  
        print(j, end=' ')
    print()

draw_grid(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm all for one-liners from time to time...

But it's much more readable for future you or other devs to understand:

```
def draw_grid(n):
    items = " ".join(str(i) for i in range(1, n+1)])
    for i in range(n):
        print(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're required to use nested loops but if not, you can also do it with one loop.

```
def draw_grid(n):
    for i in range(n):
        print(' '.join([str(i) for i in range(1, n + 1)]))

draw_grid(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `range(1, n+1)` for your outer loop its going to be the same amount regardless what number it starts at, its just keeping count of the amount of iterations, also you don't need the additional `1` the default steps are already `1`. Other than that you were just missing a `print()` before the next iteration of the outer loop begins.

```
def draw_grid(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(1, n + 1):
            print(j, end=' ')
        print()

draw_grid(3)
```